# Alternatives to jelly for jenkins frontend

Tags: jenkins, jelly

Are there alternatives to using more modern frontend languages such as react to do the frontend for jenkin plugins?

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice blogbost about newer javascript library support:
[ui plugins blog post](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2020/03/17/ui-plugins/)

Comment: I've come across this as well as a react-jenkins plugin. However, the reason im looking for an alternative is because the dev's are not familiar with jelly or serverside rendering. 

The look and feel of the ui is not much of an issue as we are alreayd styling it quite well.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-monitor-plugin/